# Are solutions of linear Equations vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

Let's say we have an equation $x+y=0$, Now the solutions to this equation can be $(x=-1,y=1)$, $(x=2,y=-2)$.

Now are the solutions to the equation vectors?

Because when we represent them in coordinate axes we do it like there is a difference between $x=1$ and $y=1$, they are considered with a specific direction which I do not think is actually the case, is the graph just a relation between $x$ and $y$, not actual dimensions? is that the case?

Because when I was reading Elementary Linear Algebra by Howard Anton, the book claims that we are actually plotting in the $x-y$ coordinate system by which I interpret he is meaning the $x-y$ dimensions.

Also, it had said that if the solution is in $2\text{D}$ or $3\text{D}$ space? Aren't $x$ and $y$ just real numbers and not dimensions of space. Could somebody clear this up for me?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's helpful to think about the equation $x+y = 0$ as the equation for a line in two-dimensional space (which line?). If you then have a system of two linear equations, you would be finding the intersection between two lines.

With this interpretation, you can also interpret visually what happens when a system of equations has no solutions, exactly one solution, or infinitely many solutions. Indeed, two lines in the plane are either parallel or not. If they are not parallel, they have a unique intersection point, and if they are not, then they are either on top of each other, or they don't intersect at all.

You can also think of a point in the plane as a vector from the origin to that point, that way you can also think about vectors.

NB. If there are three variables, then an equation like $x + y = 0$ would be the equation for a plane. Two planes generally intersect in a line. This is what happens when you have one free parameter in the solution to the system of linear equations.

Comment: But when we plot y and x coordinates isnt that really a graph of y as a function of x not a dimensional Space graph?

Comment: Arent they just real numbers not actually points in space?

Comment: A pair of real numbers $(x,y)$ is the same as a point in two-dimensional space. There is, in general, no reason to consider $y$ as a function of $x$. When you are using those letters as labels for points on a plane, there is no good reason for them to be dependent on each other, even though this is what we do in other applications.

Comment: So is this just a representation,because for example x=1 is no different from y=1. But if you plot them in 2D space then they are different

Comment: @Wizcat what if you plot a Velocity-Time graph. x and y can be anything, Is a point in the graph also a vector?

Comment: In a $v,t$-graph, $v$ is a function of $t$, because, at every moment, a particle has a single well-defined velocity. There, I would not interpret a point $(t,v)$ as a vector, since vectors have something to do with "direction". What that implies is that we should treat $v$ and $t$ on the same footing (since, for example, we should be able to rotate vectors). But here $v$ and $t$ have different units.

The vector interpretation can be used when both $x$ and $y$ are functions of a new variable $t$. You could consider a point in two-dimensional space tracing a circle: $(x,y) = (\cos t,\sin t).$

Comment: For some variable X and some variable y isn't X a function of y? Because that's why calculus does it takes a linear equation with two variables mostly where X is a function of y,in this case y=-x. And the points that we plot for say X=1,y=-1 are just a representation is that what you are saying? That it can be represented by points in space because the graph is just a graph as y being a function of x

Comment: This is going a bit off topic, so if you want, we can continue the discussion in chat. Do you have something I could add you on?